# Java : Static methods

Tags: java

I am at beginner stage in learning java, I made a program for bubble sort. Code is as follows

```
package bubblesort;

public class Bubblesort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[] {10,20,40,30,50};
    arr = BubbleSort(arr);
    for(int i:arr) {
        System.out.println(i+" ");
    }
}

public static int[] BubbleSort(int[] arr) {
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        for(int j =i+1;j<arr.length;j++) {
            if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

}
```

My question is as following :
"Since a static method can only take static data variables as parameters, then why 'BubbleSort' function in my program is not reporting any error because of arr not being a static variable ?"

Comment: A parameter cannot be static or instance as it is local to the method. Same for a variable declared inside of a method; it too is *local* and static has no meaning there.

Answer (score 2):

> Since a static method can only take static data variables as parameters

Incorrect.

A `static` method can only *directly reference* other `static` members, not instance members.  This refers to class-level fields, methods, etc.

But any method can *accept as a parameter/argument* any value you pass to it.  And can *internally declare and use* any local variable it wants.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods neither know nor care where the parameters came from in the first place. It doesn't matter that it's a local variable because it has a reference to the array.

What you *actually* can't do is "directly" refer to instance methods or fields from a static method because, by definition, it needs a specific instance to call those methods on.

Answer (score 0):

A static method can only access static *members of its containing type*. So in your case the `BubbleSort` method cannot access any *instance* fields or methods  of the `BubbleSort` class. Arguments and local variables are of course always allowed.